# nested directives and prototypal inheritance

Tags: angularjs

Usually when using an isolated scope, I pass my model object using an intermediate vm object, in order to avoid prototypal inheritance issue.

Say, I have a directive directiveA

```
 function directiveA() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
         myParam: '='
        },
    ...
   }
 }
```

And I would call it like that in the html:

```
<directive-a  my-param="vm.someProperty"></directive-a>
```

But now I have a scenario with nested properties and I don't see how to pass my model without running into the prototypal inheritance issue:

```
function directiveB(){
 return {
     restrict: 'E',
     require: '^directiveA',
     scope: true
 }
}
```

So if in directiveB I assign a new value to scope.myParam, it is going to create a new object on the scope of directiveB instead of modifying the myParam property on directiveA's scope.

How can I avoid this issue ?

Comment: How do you use `directiveB`? Depending on that it may not even have access to the scope of `directiveA`.

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER**

To avoid the issue, pass the whole object of vm to the scope directive,

```
<directive-a  my-param="vm"></directive-a>
```

and

```
<directive-b  my-param="vm"></directive-b>
```

*Note:* Assume that `vm` object comes from its parent controller.

---

---

**LONG ANSWER**

In your answer, when you pass the `vm.someProperty`, you actually **pass the value** of that property to `myParam`, thus creating a new scope that is independent to its parent controller. To be able to modify the property from parent scope, do **pass the reference** of the `vm` object.

**How do pass by value and pass by reference work in Javascript?**
`object.property = "newProperty"` is passing by value while `object = oldObject` is passing by reference.
Here, I created an example of how this works,

**JS**

```
// Pass By Value
var a = "helloProperty";
var b = a;
b = "modifiedProperty";
console.log(a); // prints helloProperty

// Pass By Value
var c = {};
c.someProperty = "helloProperty2";
var d = c.someProperty;
d = "modifiedProperty2";
console.log(c); // prints helloProperty2

// Pass By Reference
var e = {};
e.someProperty = "helloProperty3";
var f = {};
f = e;
f.someProperty = "modifiedProperty3";
console.log(e); // prints modifiedProperty3
```

[CODE](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/kaiKF)

---

**Back to the original problem**

As it has been said in the short answer, setting up the isolated scope to pass by reference will not create a new scope and any change will modify its parent scope.

Here is the solution to the problem,

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS: Nested Directives Accessing Scope Directives</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main" ng-controller="appController">
    <directive-a my-param="vm">
        <directive-b my-param="vm"></directive-b>
    </directive-a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['myApp.controller', 'myApp.directive']);

angular.module('myApp.controller', []).controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.vm = {
        someProperty: ''
    };
    $scope.vm.someProperty = 'someVmProperty';
}]);

angular.module('myApp.directive', [])
    .directive('directiveA', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                myParam: '='
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            }],
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                console.log(scope.myParam); // prints Object {someProperty: "modifiedProperty"}
            }
        }
    }).
    directive('directiveB', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^directiveA',
            scope: {
                myParam: '='
            },
            controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
            }],
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.myParam.someProperty = 'modifiedProperty';
            }
        }

    });
```

[CODE](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/DeusC)

Hope this will help you out. Cheers